# Recursive algorithm to solve change-making problem

Tags: algorithm, recursion, coin-change

I want to make a recursive algorithm that solves the change-making problem. Is it possible to use a non-dynamic approach that not only returns the minimum number of coins but also returns the set of coins used to make-up the given value,

For example, given the value 6 and the set of coins=[1, 3, 4]. Is it possible to make a recursive algorithm that doesn't memoise that can return both the minimum number of coins (2) and the set of coins (3,3)?

EDIT: This is my current algorithm but it only returns the total number of coins:

```
int makeChangeRecursive(int[] coins, int numCoins, int amount)
   int r, l;
   if (A == 0) return 0;
   else if (n == -1 || A < 0) return -1;
   r = makeChangeRecursive(coins, numCoins - 1, amount);
   l = 1 + makeChangeRecursive(coins, numCoins, amount - coins[numCoins]);
   if (r == -1 && l == 0) return -1;
   else if ((r == -1 || l < r) && l != 0) return l;
   return r;

makeChangeRecursive({1, 2, 5}, 2, 11);
```

would return 3 but I want it to also provide the set {5, 5, 1}. The second argument (2) is the number of coins minus 1.

Comment: If you have the set of coins, do you really need the number of coins? After all, you should be able to just get the number of items in the set.

Comment: My question concerns finding out the set from a recursive algorithm. I'm able to find the total number of coins but not to generate the set itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and pretty straightforward.

You just need to consider the element you return: here an `int`, to be a `struct (int + history)`
and the function which aggregates your "returned" value: here the sum `(1 + int)->int` to track the history modification along

```
int -> 1 + int
// becomes
(int, history) -> (int+1, history + pieceTaken)
```

Consider the struct

```
struct NbCoin {
  int nbCoin;
  vector<int> history; // array of pieces you took during recursion
}

//now makeChangeRecursive returns the number of coin AND history
NbCoin makeChangeRecursive(int[] coins, int numCoins, int amount)
    int r, l;
    if (A == 0) return { nbCoin: 0, history: []}; //like before but with the empty history
    else if (n == -1 || A < 0) return { nbCoin: -1, history: []}; // idem

    // now contains our history as well
    r = makeChangeRecursive(coins, numCoins - 1, amount);

    // here you are taking some coin, so track it into history
    l = makeChangeRecursive(coins, numCoins, amount - coins[numCoins]);
    l = { 
      nbCoin: 1 + l.nbCoin, // like before
      history : l.history.concat(coins[numCoins]) // pieceTaken is coins[numCoins]
      // concat should create a __new__ array merging l.history and coins[numCoins]
    }

    // put nbCoin everywhere as our comparison key
    if (r.nbCoin == -1 && l.nbCoin == 0) return { nbCoin: -1, []};
    else if ((r.nbCoin == -1 || l.nbCoin < r.nbCoin) && l.nbCoin != 0) return l;
    return r;

makeChangeRecursive({1, 2, 5}, 2, 11);
```

Everywhere where you were managing the number of coin, you manage the `struct.nbCoin`, and you update the history alongside.

I have not checked whether your algorithm is ok, trusting you.

The code I modified is now not java valid, up to you to implement!